# How to save several text written using fillText on canvas to Google chrome cache

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an image on my canvas . the canvas is annotated with text on top of the image. I wrote the text using canvas.fillText(). How do i save this text to the google chrome cache. I can use HTML5 or js.

Comment: You want the text to be saved or the image? I'd like to know why...

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the text in variables as you write it on to the canvas.  The canvas element does not retain the internal structure of what you've written on to it, once something is drawn it's just pixels, the only way to get it back would be to implement some sort of [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) in JavaScript.

If you want to retain the structure of the elements you're adding to a dynamic picture then [use SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-map-element.html#svg-0) instead.